# I am trying to upload APK File but only aab file option is available

Tags: android, google-play-console

I am trying to upload APK File but only aab file option is available. When i uploaded apk file i got following alert "Upload Valid APK". For new project created in Play console.

Is .apk file support disabled by play store for new apps?

[play console upload app bundle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oRGw6.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of August 2021 for any new apps on the store you must use the App Bundle format.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/06/the-future-of-android-app-bundles-is.html

Answer (score 0):

use apktoaabconverter.com or Manually convert apk to aab with aapt2 compile into flat files
then aapt2 link to create resources into protobuf
then make base.zip and build-bundle command to create aab